# Best framework to create mobile applications?

Tags: frameworks

I'm looking for a Framework to create mobile applications, if possible writing all code in Java. The idea is create for all mobiles Android, iOS, Windows Phone etc.

I found: Sencha, Vaadin and others.

What's the best ?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it

Answer (score 1):

if you need to build cross mobile application you can use phonegap http://phonegap.com/ it is better you can use javascript and HTML and CSS to build applications.

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin is another great one. I think you're asking the wrong question though. There isn't really a BEST one, its more what fits into your style. Some might say phonegap is the best, but you can't use code behind in phonegap only HTML CSS and JavaScript. So you gotta find what works best with what you want to do.

Also, look up chrome web apps. You can now develop apps using chrome rendering engine and usual html css and other web based code types and package into apps for the different os app stores.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone is talking about [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/), I am using it and I love it. Here are some [slides](http://ionicframework.com/present-ionic/slides/#/) to introduce you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/), is based on [apache cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/), and use [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/). If you dont know AngularJS you have other alternatives like [goratchet](http://goratchet.com/) made by bootstrap creators. The only 'problem' is that you'll have to use javascript, html and css, not Java.

Answer (score 0):

I am using ionic framework as well. The best part is you do simple command like `ionic build ios` to have an ios version of your app, as well as `ionic build android` for android version. 
AngularJS is actually easy to learn (as long as you have basic understanding of JS), the best resource would be `egghead.io`. I use Ruby on Rails as backend to render an API for my ionic app to consume, so i pretty much don't need to use NodeJS or other JS framework as backend. Also, there is a lot of support for ionic. You can always search Google for a codepen example if you need help.